# how to group same date and show in one bar highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, date, highcharts

im trying to get the dates of a user selected in between 2 dates so with dates it will show data from database on the 2 dates in between. I have created the form and i also have the bar chart ready, now i just have a problem in sending back the date and the data for the selected dates but in the backend i tried dd(); it shows me the correct data but when i tried output it with {!! json_encode($categories) !!} categories being the date it displays like this:

[image]

how can i make the same date group under one bar ?

My backend is like :

```html
public function graphTest(Request $request, $companyID)
{
  $sessionID = [];
  $data = [];

  $categories = [];

  $details = DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->whereBetween('date_access', [$request->get('fromTest'), $request->get('toTest')])->get();

  foreach($details as $key => $value)
  {
    if(!array_key_exists($value->sessionid, $sessionID))
    {
      $sessionID[$value->sessionid] = $value->sessionid;
    }
  }

  foreach($sessionID as $key => $value)
  {

    $categories = $details->pluck('date_access')->toArray();

    $countMatch = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Match')->get());
    $countNoAnswer = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'No Answer')->get());
    $countMissingIntent = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Missing Intent')->get());
    $countWebhookFail = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Webhook Fail')->get());
    $countLowConfidence = count(DiraChatLog::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('sessionID', $key)->where('status', 'Low Confidence')->get());
    $totalQuestion = $countMatch + $countNoAnswer + $countMissingIntent + $countWebhookFail + $countLowConfidence;
    $data[$key] = [
                    'total' => $totalQuestion,
                    'match' => $countMatch,
                    'no answer' => $countNoAnswer,
                    'missing intent' => $countMissingIntent,
                    'webhook fail' => $countWebhookFail,
                    'low confidence' => $countLowConfidence,
                  ];
  }

  // dd($categories);

  $countTotalRecord = $this->countTotalRecord($data);

  return view('AltHr.Chatbot.graph', compact('countTotalRecord', 'companyID', 'categories'));
}
```

Comment: please show the output you want

Comment: i cant show how it will look like because i havent got there but i want it to show is for example in the picture i have selected date range between 1 Nov - 3 Nov so i want all the 1 Nov to be in one bar then 2 Nov in second bar and 3 Nov in third bar so in total my bar chart will have 3 bars with the date below in the X Axis.

Comment: try [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart/)

Comment: its nit about the charts, its the backend sending back is the problem, i have tried amcharts too